# How long will pressure exist in this case?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, pressure, heat-engine

I'm currently fabricating my project, which currently exists only on paper, and there's one question to which I have stumbled today.

Suppose, that I have a pressure vessel capable of holding upto 2000PSI pressure. I fill this vessel ~ 90% with water. Now I would start heating the pressure vessel so that the temperature of superheated steam reacher ~ 300C. Now obviously, pressure would start increasing and it would be almost 10Mpa ~ 1450PSI. *So that's the setup.* After I attain 1450PSI of pressure, I'll start releasing this pressure through a **4** nozzles of ***1 Square Inch*** and following are three different scenrios:

1. The supply of heat is still constant
2. The supply of heat is gradually increasing.
3. The supply of heat is completely stopped.

What I want to know is that, in these three different scenario, for how long will the pressure remain constant (or almost constant) after it starts getting released through **4** nozzles of 1 Sq. Inch.

Or if in case the pressure can't remain constant (or almost constant) then is there any way to make it almost constant even after releasing pressure through nozzles?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you don't seriously intend to try this project in the real world.  There are several issues that WILL lead to failure and/or serious bodily harm:

1) The water will expand as it is heated.  If you start with a container that is too full of water, it will burst the sides of the container before you get to 300 C.

2) Pressure vessels lose some strength as they get hotter.

3) The shape of the pressure vessel is critical.  The best shape is a sphere.  A cylinder should have hemispherical ends.  These shapes ensure that the shell of the vessel is only under tension, meaning that these shapes maximize the chance that the pressure vessel will be able to contain the hot water without rupturing.

4) The expanding superheated water will exit the nozzles at approximately sonic velocity, generating an enormous amount of thrust.  Hopefully, you will have your pressure vessel SECURELY attached to something else.

5) As soon as you open the nozzles, the superheated water in your pressure vessel will VIGOROUSLY boil, and the heat to support that boiling will come from the superheated water, which will rapidly lose temperature as the pressure drops.  Unfortunately, you will not be able to find any device that can add heat to the remaining water fast enough to maintain pressure.  For example, the best way to increase heat transfer is to maximize the heater area in contact with the water, then maximize the temperature difference between your heater and the water.  Unfortunately, once you have a heating element that is approximately 100 deg F hotter than the water, the boiling from the heater surfaces will be so vigorous that film boiling will occur, which will effectively insulate the heater surface from the water that you are attempting to boil.  This rate of heat transfer is guaranteed to be lower than what is needed to hold the boiling temperature, and hence the desired pressure, in your pressure vessel.

6) If your pressure vessel ruptures due to any of the above issues, you will have MAJOR problems.  Pieces of hot pressure vessel wall will be flying at high velocity, and superheated water and steam will be sprayed all over the immediate vicinity.  If you happen to be simultaneously bullet proof and fire proof, this project might be something you would want to try.

For examples of what you are trying, see episodes of MythBusters, in which they deliberately WAY overheated a hot water heater, from a SAFE distance, and behind bullet proof plexiglass.